# Consume WCF with basicHttpBinding and MTOM encoding from WP7

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, mtom

Is it possible to use basichttpbinding with MTOM messageEncoding from Windows Phone 7?
I never find it a clear document with available bindings for WP7.
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

Afraid not.  "Textual XML and Binary encodings are supported in Silverlight, but the MTOM encoding is not supported."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197959(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: I wonder if Binary encoding is available. I'm trying to send a large file from wp7 to a webservice, I'm try to figure out what is the best way to do it.

Comment: This post indicates it might be: http://www.leastprivilege.com/WindowsPhone7AndWSTrust.aspx

Comment: You could upload it just using the HttpWebRequest class, writing it to the stream you get from BeginGetRequestStream.  Note though that the client won't start sending the data until you call BeginGetResonse ie you can't really stream the data - it will all be buffered in memory.  I suspect that all other layers on top of HttpWebRequest, including WCF, will face the same restriction.